# Bubble like fur with displacement modifer

Tags: texturing, modifiers

What kind of texture would I need to use to get what you see on the left, with a displacement modifer?

[image]

The left hand side model is made with sculpt mode and dynotopo, but that of course ruins the topology.

I tried using black circle texture to no avail, and kind of stuck on what kind of texture I would need to create to achieve what I'm after.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated, blend attached!

[image]

Comment: you could blur this texture to use it in the Displace modifier, but the UV unwrap needs to be seamless which seems difficult, or use just use one of these blurred sphere as a pattern that you paint all over the surface and use the result as a Displace texture, but anyway Duarte's procedural solution seems much easier

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like the job for a Voronoi type of texture.

You may have to invert the *Strength* parameter of the modifier to a negative value get the displayed result.

Adjust the size value and play around with intensity and distance metrics to get the perfect feel. 
*Distance Squared* gave me the closest feel to what you show. Make sure your mesh subdivided enough, high density is required for sharp corners.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hmm. I don't get the same results as your gif on my actual model I want it to be applied too. it's becomes very sharp and like jagged.

Comment: I just did, so you are missing something. Make sure your mesh subdivided enough

Comment: Thanks again for this, I figured out the strength of the weights in the vertex group play a big part as well. getting some cool effects with other textures now!

Comment: It's not a tumor!